# preload and postload page event using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two function.

one is for prePageLoad and other is for postPageLoad

How to call this functions with these events accordingly ?

This is the same situation like loading image would be visible when page starting to load and hide when page loaded successfully.

Any solution related to javascript or jquery needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could run your first function instantly, and the second like this: `window.onload = postPageLoad;` which then would be run when your page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

1.`<body onload="prePageLoad()">`

2.on footer call onload="postPageLoad()"